# Сохранение файла в облаке

Tags: c#, облако

Так. Надеюсь правильно поставлю вопрос. Такое задание: нужно в windows form сохранять выбранный файл в облако. При чем, я просто прописала открытие в WebBrowser ссылки на облако..ну для примера делаю в облаке mail. Но все..вход в облачное хранилище не работает (другие вкладки открывает). Это первая проблема. Вторая...как туда передавать тот файл который я выбрала с помощью OpenFileDialog? Помогите пожалуйста. Потому что меня занесло в дебри. Может стоит работать по другому. Спасибо вам огромное заранее. Выручайте

Comment: Я не уверен, но наверное для начала надо бы поискать, есть ли API у нужного вам облака или ещё лучше SDK, и его уже использовать. Ну, и также не мешает гуглить https://habrahabr.ru/post/281360/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сохранения файла в облако (любое) вам надо сначала получить токен, а потом использовать его для отправки файла.

Облако mail.ru не имеет общедоступного API. Можно использовать методы реверс-инженеринга, как указано в статье  [habrahabr.ru/post/281360](http://habrahabr.ru/post/281360) которую предложил tym32167, но это плохое решение, т.к. недокументированный API может поменяться в любой момент без обратной совместимости.

Рекомендую использовать облака Google Drive или DropBox.

У обоих сервисов есть прекрасно документированные API с библиотеками и примерами.

Google Drive - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v3

DropBox - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet 
Вот тут есть довольно простые готовые примеры авторизации и отправки файла в облако https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Examples/SimpleTest/Program.cs

Comment: Спасибо большое.