# Как залить изображение на любой хостинг изображений используя C#

Tags: c#, .net, хостинг-изображений

Как я могу залить картинку на какой нибудь хостинг картинок и получить в return прямую ссылку на картинку?
Гуглил уже миллион раз, на форумах ответы по такой теме только за 2012й год, естестенной давно не актуальные (к примеру потому, что таких сервисов как там описывают уже давно не существует или апи сервиса полностью изменили)
В общем нет не то что "работающих" вариантов, нет ничего похожего что мне могло бы пригодиться.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Похожий вопрос 2017 года http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663640/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи библиотеки NetTCP попробуй:

```
new WebClient().FileUpload("http://адрес/страница","Адрес откуда будет закинут");
```